# How to solve this CodingBat encoder problem?

Tags: java, methods, encode

Problem link: https://codingbat.com/prob/p238573

Requirement:
Write a function that replaces the words in `raw` with the words in `code_words` such that the first occurrence of each word in `raw` is assigned the first unassigned word in `code_words`.

encoder(["a"], ["1", "2", "3", "4"]) → ["1"]

encoder(["a", "b"], ["1", "2", "3", "4"]) → ["1", "2"]

encoder(["a", "b", "a"], ["1", "2", "3", "4"]) → ["1", "2", "1"]

I tried two different solutions but it still shows that my function doesn't work on "other tests"

First:

```
public String[] encoder(String[] raw, String[] code_words) {
          HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
          for (int i=raw.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
              hm.put(raw[i], code_words[i]);
          }
            
          
          String [] finalarray = new String[raw.length];
          for (int i=0; i < raw.length; i++) {
            String x = hm.get(raw[i]);
            finalarray[i] = x;
          }
          return finalarray;
        }
```

All tests were fine, but the "other tests" failed

> so I thought it was because of this line in requirements
> the first occurrence of each word in `raw` is assigned the first ***unassigned*** word in `code_words`

so I updated the code to this:

```
public String[] encoder(String[] raw, String[] code_words) {
          HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
          for (int i=0; i < raw.length; i++) {
            String word = raw[i];
            String value = code_words[i];
            if (!hm.containsKey(word)) {
                if (hm.containsValue(value)) {
                    for (int i1=0; i1 < code_words.length; i1++) {
                        value = code_words[i1];
                        if (!hm.containsValue(value)) {
                            hm.put(word, value);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                
                }
                else {
                    hm.put(word, value);
                }
                
                }   
            }
          String[] finalarray = new String[raw.length];
          for (int i=0; i < raw.length; i++) {
              String x = hm.get(raw[i]);
              finalarray[i] = x;
          }
        return finalarray;
    }
```

But it failed and I don't know why is that.

**EDIT:**
The problem with my (Second) code was:
if we assume raw = {"a", "a", "b", "d"}
and code words = {"1", "2", "3", "4"}

my code would assign letter "a" to "1" and "b" to "3" and d to "4"
that would leave "2" unassigned even though, it was the first unassigned letter

the code I provided an work with few adjustments

```
public String[] encoder(String[] raw, String[] code_words) {
          HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
          for (int i=0; i < raw.length; i++) {
            String word = raw[i];
            int assigned = 0;
            String value = code_words[assigned];
            if (!hm.containsKey(word)) {
                if (hm.containsValue(value)) {
                    for (int i1=0; i1 < code_words.length; i1++) {
                        value = code_words[i1];
                        if (!hm.containsValue(value)) {
                            hm.put(word, value);
                            assigned++;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                
                }
                else {
                    hm.put(word, value);
                    assigned++;
                }
                
                }   
            }
          String[] finalarray = new String[raw.length];
          for (int i=0; i < raw.length; i++) {
              String x = hm.get(raw[i]);
              finalarray[i] = x;
          }
        return finalarray;
    }
```

but it's definitely more efficient to use the code provided below. thanks to the contributors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

Your first idea wasn't all that bad. The problem is, that you should replace **all** occurrences of a word in `raw` with the first unassigned word in `code_words`.

### How to fix

Lets first analyse how to fix your first code. Your idea of using a HashMap is pretty good. Clearly, if a word of `raw` already exists in the HashMap you don't want to add it a second time, so you just skip it in your first iteration.
Now, if the **i**th word in `raw` has no assigned value in your HashMap, you should add it the first unassigned word of `code_words`, which may have a different index than i, so we assign it another index, let's say j. After that, the **j**th word has been assigned and the first unassigned word has index j+1.
After iterating like that once over `raw`, every word has an assigned code in your HashMap and you can iterate over it one more time and assign the values.

### The Code

Your final code will look something like this:

```java
public String[] encoder(String[] raw, String[] code_words) {
    HashMap<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
    String[] coded = new String[raw.length];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
        if(!dictionary.containsKey(raw[i])) { //if it has no assigned value
            dictionary.put(raw[i], code_words[j]); //add to hashmap
            j++; //set index to next unassigned
        }
        //do nothing if already found before
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
        coded[i] = dictionary.get(raw[i]); //get coded word and set in final array
    }
    return coded;
}
```

We can write this somewhat more compacter, which some may prefer and other might find more confusing, so it's up to you.

```java
public String[] encoder(String[] raw, String[] code_words) {
    HashMap<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<>();
    String[] coded = new String[raw.length];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
        if(!dictionary.containsKey(raw[i])) { //if it has no assigned value
            dictionary.put(raw[i], code_words[j++]); //add to hashmap and also increment index of code_words
        }
        coded[i] = dictionary.get(raw[i]);
    }
    return coded;
}
```

This last code passed all tests.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I get the point, but i thought of this on my code, so when my code comes a cross an assigned value, it starts from index 0 at code_words(line 8) and checks the whole array again. of course your code seems to be much more efficient but i don't know whats causing my code to fail

Comment: nvm, i figured out

Answer (score 1):

You're making it a lot more complex than it is.

Yes, you need the `hm` map, and yes, you only add to it if the `raw` word isn't already a key in the map.

But to keep track of the next unassigned `code_word`, all you need is an *index* into the `code_words` array.

```java
Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
int unassigned = 0;
for (String word : raw) {
    if (! hm.containsKey(word)) {
        hm.put(word, code_words[unassigned]);
        unassigned++;
    }
}
```

The code of the entire method can be compacted to:

```java
public String[] encoder(String[] raw, String[] code_words) {
    String[] encoded = new String[raw.length];
    Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0, unassigned = 0; i < raw.length; i++)
        if ((encoded[i] = hm.get(raw[i])) == null)
            hm.put(raw[i], encoded[i] = code_words[unassigned++]);
    return encoded;
}
```

Comment: Wow! I really wish I could approve 2 answers :D this is very helpful, thanks a lot. but if possible, can you tell me why the loop i made on line 8 didn't work as the variable unassigned in your function? of course yours is waaaaaaaaay more efficient but I just need to understand whats failing

Comment: nvm, i figured out

Answer (score 1):

Just update one line

```
hm.put(raw[i], code_words[raw[i].charAt(0)-'a']);
```